# Facebook page admin did not have publish actions permission

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, coldfusion, facebook-access-token

I want to do a facebook post from my coldfusion application to a test page. I have created a test page and I am the admin of that page. Now I got the API key and Page ID with the given details. The issue is when I post the request to facebook using

```
 <cfhttp url="https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/#MyPageID#/feed" result="access" >
        <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="access_token" value="#MyAccessToken#" />
        <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="message" value="#MyMessage#" />
 </cfhttp>
```

I am getting all the posts from my page and the message is not posted. Can anyone help? Please let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: did you use facebook graph api? or anything else?

Comment: Yes. I am using the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh. It is just a simple mistake and it made me to hang for hours. After wasting much hours, I have found that the **HTTP call method must be post**.

```
<cfhttp url="https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/#MyPageID#/feed" result="access" method="false">
  <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="access_token" value="#MyAccessToken#" />
  <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="message" value="#MyMessage#" />
</cfhttp>
```

So the final lesson is, when the method is get, it reads the posts and when it is post, it adds a new post.